# Moving file error during build phase in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I get this when building .apk in Unity. I've tried to restart the PC, run Unity with Administrator privileges but it doesn't work. I'm lost.

Console output:

```
    IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-core-11.2.0\classes.jar' to 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-core-11.2.0\libs\classes.jar'.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.ProcessAAR.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Any help appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/19#issuecomment-328643454

Answer (score 0):

I've had this on occasion. My fix is to either change the version of the app in peeferences or to erase the app from my device.
Sometimes, it is as simple as restarting Unity.